# Bootstrap 3 popover doesn't work in "responsive" mode

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t4unwqL9/2/) for full code example.

Notice how you can hover over that orange road glyphicon and it correctly displays my popover? Well, when I shrink the width of the **Result** section down to the point that the menus stack vertically, and then I hover over the popover, it doesn't render. To me, this means it won't render when a user is viewing my app from a mobile browser.

I tried:

```
#fieldMode .popover {
    min-width: 300px
}

#fieldMode .popover-title {
    color: rgb(255,102,0);
    background: rgb(176,205,249);
}

#fieldMode .popover-content {
    color: rgb(12,66,144)
}
```

...but that doesn't seem to work. What's the fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On mobile, your `a` tag is given `display: block` by the bootstrap styles, causing to to be 100% width. This won't work if you're trying to position the popover to the right of it. Adding `display: inline-block` will cause it to only take up the space it needs instead of the full screen width. Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mgup49hv/1/

```
#fieldModePopover {
    display: inline-block;    
}
```

Comment: My sincerest apologies @Stever Sanders (+1) - it seems I posted an old version of my CSS in that jsFiddle. Please see my [latest jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4unwqL9/2/) that has the correct CSS. I tried your change on it and it doesn't work. Ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb it sure does work :) updated your new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3zahh3w6/

Comment: Nice @Stever Sanders (+1 again)! Hey, how'd you get the footer to be sticky?!? I love it!